# Transaction problem using REQUIRES_NEW in a for loop with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions

I need to process a list of elements and, if an Exception (or RuntimeException) occurs, it cannot undo the job done previously. It must only undo the database operation in that time and the other elements must continue to be processed.

My strategy was to create a class with *propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED* with a for loop and, inside of it, I would call another method with *propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW*.

```
Transaction 1->
    loop -> transaction 2
         -> transaction 3
         -> ...
         -> transaction N
end of transaction 1
```

In this strategy, if occurs an Exception in transaction 2 it will be rollbacked and transaction 3 will continue normally.

**Problem:** if occurs an Exception in transaction 2, it is not rollbacked and transaction 3 continues normally. Transaction 1 is not affected.

*If I add an **throw e** in the catch block of Service2* and it occurs an Exception in transaction 3, it is rollbacked and transaction 2 is not affected (so far so good), but transaction 1 receives the Exception and the process stops, not processing the remaining elements.

> What I doing wrong? =/

Code:

```
package test.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DefaultController {

    @Autowired
    private Service1 service1;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() throws Exception {
        service1.m1();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This controller calls a service:

```
package test.controller;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class Service1 {

    @Autowired
    private Service2 service2;

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void m1() {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2);

        for (Integer j : list) {
            service2.m2(j);
            System.out.println("Exception for j = " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

And this service1 calls a service2, because I knew that Spring Boot AOP is proxy based, then I needed another bean to switch the Propagation of my transactions:

```
package test.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import test.model.domain.Log;
import test.service.LogService;

@Service
public class Service2 {

    @Autowired
    private LogService logger;

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void m2(int i) {

        try {
            Log log = new Log();
            log.setDataMensagem(new Date());
            log.setDescricaoEnvioRecebimento("TEST");
            log.setDescricaoMensagem("TEST1");
            log.setIdMensagem("TEST2");
            log.setNomeFilaServico("TESTE3");
            logger.save(log);

            if (i == 2) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("RuntimeException in i = " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

The LogService:

```
package test.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import test.indicador.LogFilaServicoIndicador;
import test.model.domain.Log;
import test.repository.LogRepository;

@Service
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class LogService {

    private final LogRepository repository;

    public LogService(LogRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Log save(Log logFilaServico) {
        return repository.save(logFilaServico);
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
package test.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import test.model.domain.Log;

@Repository
public interface LogRepository extends CrudRepository<Log, Long> {

}
```

Comment: m2 never throws an exception, so Spring will never rollback its transaction. The catch must be inside m1, in the for loop. Not in m2().

Comment: @JBNizet If I add "throw e" in the catch block of m2(), the transaction is rollback (so far so good), but the original transaction too! (the transactional 1 of my example). In my thoughts, the exception would stop only the inner transaction, not the original of m1(). Does it make sense?

Comment: m1's transaction won't be rolbacked if you catch the exception thrown by m2(). Remove the try/catch in m2, and put it inside the for loop of m1() (As I already said in my first comment)

Comment: And BTW, m1 doesn't need to be transactional at all. Itt's just a loop over 2 integers. You don't need a transaction for that.

Comment: @JBNizet Your sugestion in comment 2 works properly, thanks! But I still have a question: if I am handling exceptions using try catch, why should I need to configure m2() as REQUIRES_NEW? I thought that only using the transactions I could solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Because since m1 is transactional, using REQUIRES for m2 would simply do all the work of m2 inside the unique, single transaction created for m1. Any exception thrown by m2 would rollback the unique m1 transaction. If m1 is not transactional (and none of its callers is), then m2 can use REQUIRES, since REQUIRES and REQUIRES_NEW would both have the same effect of starting a new transaction for m2.

Comment: @JBNizet, I did as you suggested: I removed the REQUIRED from m1() and I changed to REQUIRED in m2(). Addidionally, I removed the try catch from the loop in m1(). This time, the first element was processed and saved correctly, but the second don't (so far so good). Besides m1() is not transactional, the exception in m2() stopped the whole execution. Was this behavior that you expected?

Comment: *Addidionally, I removed the try catch from the loop in m1().*: why? Obviously, if you don't catch the exception, it will propagate to the caller. That's how exceptions work. You need to read about exceptions. It's fundamental stuff. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: @JBNizet, I think I understood what you told, thank you!. I think I am making a confusion in my mind about the usage of transactions because I thought that only using the Transactional and the proper Propagations, if an Exceptions occurs, the transactionManager would handle the situation without try catch blocks (but aparently not based on your explanations).

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you for helping, I read some stuff and I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @JBNizet help, to solve the problem I needed to:

1) Remove the @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) from m1().

2) Changing the REQUIRES_NEW to REQUIRED in m2() and remove the try catch block from m2() and put add a tryc catch block in m1(), because it needs to handle the Exception without stopping the m1() execution.

So I have:

```
public void m1() {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2);

        for (Integer j : list) {
            try {
                service2.m2(j);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception for j = " + j);
            }
        }
    }
```

And m2():

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void m2(int i) {

    Log log = new Log();
    log.setDataMensagem(new Date());
    log.setDescricaoEnvioRecebimento("TEST");
    log.setDescricaoMensagem("TEST1");
    log.setIdMensagem("TEST2");
    log.setNomeFilaServico("TESTE3");
    logger.save(log);

    if (i == 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: No change to propagations required.

Comment: @Lucas Amorim Silva so Service1 is not a spring managed bean anymore? Can we make services non-transactional?

Answer (score 0):

To rollback m2, your exception must cross the aop wrapper of service2.

That in turn will just ultimately bubble up as it should to m1. You are still responsible to write proper java code if you want to continue to j=3...

Catch it in the for loop as you would normally do.
All your @Transactional are correct.